# Vertically expanding fieldEditor for an NSTextFieldCell

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, nstextfield, nstextfieldcell, fieldeditor

`NSWindow`s have a "field editor" associated with them, which is an `NSText` that appears in the same place as a `NSTextField` or `NSTextFieldCell` when the user focuses on the aforementioned control.

Field editors have the same size as the `NSTextField` or `NSTextFieldCell`. As the user enters more text, I'd need the field editor to expand.

Any tips on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [IFVerticallyExpandingTextField](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/IFVerticallyExpandingTextField). The code is a bit old (and so is your question), and not sure if it's still useable with the current API, but maybe it will get you started.